# Assigning null value to a nullable enum through :? operator

Tags: c#, enums, operators

I am trying to initialize the following object:

```
return new ObjectNaturalPerson
            {
                Initials = entity.Initials,
                FirstName = entity.FirstName,
                LastName = entity.LastName,
                Gender = GetGender(entity.Gender),
                BirthPlace = entity.Birthplace
            };
```

So far there is no problem with the code.
But focus on the line:

```
Gender = GetGender(entity.Gender)
```

What I want to achieve is that I would like to set Gender to **null** or **GetGender(entity.Gender)** depending on **entity.Gender**, which is a string.
Moreover, Gender is a nullable property, named indeed Gender and of type Gender, which is an enum.

```
public Gender? Gender { get; set; }
```

What I don't understand is that, if during the object initalization I try to set directly **Gender = null**, there is no problem! Instead, if try to use the operators **:?** in the following way then I receive an error:

```
Gender = entity.Gender.IsNullOrEmpty() ? null : GetGender(entity.Gender)
```

The error is: type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between Null and Gender. But again, if I set Gender directly to null then there is no problem! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does GetGender do?  You should post that code since its pretty critical to your issue.  Why cant it just return a null?  Some basic debugging will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe cast null to Gender. ?(Gender) null:

Comment: @SurjitSD how would that help?

Comment: @maccettura  GetGender returns an enum. Gender is a property of type Enum.

Comment: @maccettura since null will be cast to nullable of Gender. So the conditional operator should not throw error

Comment: Gender = entity.Gender.IsNullOrEmpty() ? (Gender?)null : GetGender(entity.Gender)

////// This code should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: @Tarta why cant you just make `GetGender` return a nullable (i.e `Gender?`)

Comment: The `?` operator indeed complains if it can't detect the type from the first arg. Either invert the null check and put the identifiable argument first, or cast null to the intended type.

Comment: @GarrisonBecker that was correct!